# Extracting first names from list of full names in Python

Tags: python

I've got a list of full names from a csv file, but I only want to apply my next piece of code to the first names from that list. The list looks like this:

```
['michelle rodriguez', 'dexter king', 'gurukavari']
```

But then for a few thousand names. As you can see, some of the names don't contain a last name, and some do. How do I create a new list which contains only the first names from this list?

Comment: `[w.split()[0] for w in lst]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list-comprehension:

```
lst = ['michelle rodriguez', 'dexter king', 'gurukavari'] 
print([x.split()[0] for x in lst])

# ['michelle', 'dexter', 'gurukavari']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map function like:-

```
a = ['michelle rodriguez', 'dexter king', 'gurukavari'] 
b= map((lambda x: x.split()[0]), a) # ['michelle', 'dexter', 'gurukavari']
```

Answer (score 0):

Would advise to use `Map` function, and to split each of the iterable items by space character, and return only the first of the split items.

Answer (score 0):

Use a split function to separate the first name & last name from the name list and traverse the list till the last element.

**Code :**

```
    names = ['michelle rodriguez', 'dexter king', 'gurukavari'] 
    firstname = []
    for i in range(0,len(names)):
        firstname.append(names[i].split()[0])
    print(firstname)
```

**Output :**

```
['michelle', 'dexter', 'gurukavari']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = "Saurabh Chandra Patel"
first_name = name.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
last_name = name.rsplit(' ', 1)[1]
```

1. first_name  = Saurabh Chandra
2. last_name  = Patel

**if name = "Saurabh Patel"**

1. first_name  = Saurabh
2. last_name  = Patel